# Rails Validating percentage range as string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I have a form that I have to validate the range of the percentages.

If its in between 0-100 it should be good

however it is coming through as a '100%' string but saves to the DB as a number 1.0

So I cant do

```
validates_inclusion_of :number, :in => 1..10
```

since it is not technically a number

I want to validate that the user puts in a number 0-100 as a percentage

Comment: What about something like this: `validates_numericality_of :number, :greater_than_or_equal_to => 0.0, :less_than_or_equal_to => 1.0`?

Comment: @trueinViso the issue with that is its getting saved as a string not a number "number"=>"220.0%",

Comment: What does your database schema look like? Sounds like it's a string not a float. Also, you might want to do validate the numericality of the `number` too. You might need a `before_validate` to trim the `%` from the number and convert it to a number

Comment: @evanbikes t.decimal  "the_field_i_want_to_validate",  default: 0.0   this is what the schema looks like

Comment: I would suggest to store the percentage as a number/float. % is only for display and every other operation needs converting this percentage string into number/float. I am a firm believer in storing the data in correct type.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should still validate the numericality and the inclusion of the field, so try converting it in a `before_validate`.

```
before_validate :convert_number_field

private

def convert_number_field
  return unless self.number.is_a? String

  self.number = number.match(/\d+\.*\d*/).try(:to_f)
end
```